# Spring Boot Service to update (PUT)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing a Spring Boot service layer to update a `Car` entity - but the issue is the added complexity of FindById methods now all returning Optional<> and also integrating the return type being a Dto not an entity.

I understand Optional<> is good in so far as it forces the developer to handle not found but I intend to add exception handlers later.

**Service**

```
@Override    
public CarCreateDto updateCar(CarCreateDto updateCarDto, Long id) {
    Optional<Car> CarOptional = CarRepository.findById(id);
    return CarOptional.map(Car -> {
        CarMapper.partialUpdate(updateCarDto, Car);
        return CarMapper.toDto(CarRepository.save(Car));
        });
}
```

The issue with the above is that the Optional<> is bubbling up through the Entity to the Dto resulting in a return type of Optional when it expects CarCreateDto.

How to best handle this simple update method on service layer and have the method return a Dto type.

Comment: you can add the following method

.orElseGet(() -> null);
at the end

Comment: Do you mind cut n pasting it into the sample code?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to return Optional<> type, replace findById with getById this method as a spring boot convention return Car type and then map it to Dto. This can be a simpler update method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the operations using [`Optional.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)). Any operation will be invoked only if the optional is not empty.

> If a value is present, returns an Optional describing (as if by ofNullable(T)) the result of applying the given mapping function to the value, otherwise returns an empty Optional.
> If the mapping function returns a null result then this method returns an empty Optional.

```
public CarCreateDto updateCar(CarCreateDto updateCarDto, Long id) {
  Optional<Car> optionalCar = carRepository.getCarById(id);
  return optionalCar.map(car -> {
    carMapper.partialupdate(updateCarDto, car);
    return car;
  })
          .map(car -> repository.save(car))
          .map(car -> CarCreateDto.fromCar(car))//your actual mapping from car to dto here
          .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("not found"));
}
```

The current handling is to throw exception, if the operations result in empty optional (or the initial one was empty), but you can use [`orElseGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)) or [`orELse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) to supply fallback value, if that's what your scenario requires.

All of [Optional javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: Thank you - any further commentary on how maps are used with Optionals would be amazing.

Comment: Does this method return object of type `Car` or `CreateCarDto` ? It should return `CreateCarDto`

Comment: @AlGrant I am not really sure what to comment. You provide a function, which transforms from initial content to a new content, which is invoked only if the optional contains a value. It is explained in details in the javadoc, and I added a quote.

Comment: Does the function return a type of `Dto?`

Comment: @AlGrant The functions return whatever you need them to return. In the first 2 `map` operations you write functions, which accept `Car` and return `Car`. In the last one write a function, which accepts `Car` and returns `CarCreateDto`. Naturally those functions can reuse your already existing methods to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are trying to achieve something like the below -

```
public CarCreateDto updateCar(CarCreateDto updateCarDto, Long id) {
        Car car = carRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Car not found"));
    
        CarMapper.partialUpdate(updateCarDto, car);
        Car updatedCar = carRepository.save(car);
    
        return CarMapper.toDto(updatedCar);
}
```